# PropTypes shape required If prop supplied

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to do complex validation using PropTypes, and I'm not having much luck in figuring it out.

Current PropTypes:

```js
Map.propTypes = {
  locations: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      latitude: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string])
        .isRequired,
      longitude: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string])
        .isRequired
    })
  )
}
```

#### What's happening:

If no `locations` prop is supplied, the latitude and longitude are still marked as required. I guess this is to be expected.

#### What I would like:

I would like it if the latitude and longitude were required *only if* the locations prop was supplied.

I have tried doing a custom function for the locations prop, but since it's got complex validation (`arrayOf`, `shape` and `oneOfType`) I didn't want reimplement those methods myself.